# Focus on input in iOS8 Makes the whole page jump

Tags: javascript, input, ios8, safari, focus

I have two problems that happen only in iOS 8:

1. I have a login form which includes two inputs for username and password. In iOS 8 Safari, when I move from input to input, the page jumps in a weird way. I found a post that describes exactly the same thing: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/2256
2. After focusing a text input by clicking on it, the window closes itself. And that's the more serious problem. Is there a way to solve it with only JavaScript/jQuery?